# Google cloud can build and tag images with podman, but can't push to registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, podman

I was able to configure Google Cloud SDK to work, and now podman is able to read the information, build and tag my container image. However, when I try to push it, it says there are no docker-credentials-gcloud installed.

I already ran `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr` and it worked fine, was able to install the component.

However, when I go in the virtual environment, I get errors with reading the credentials:

```
(.venv) spool@fedora:~/Documents/Projects/Predicting_default podman  build -t default-service-fastpai:latest .
STEP 1/8: FROM python:3.10-slim
STEP 2/8: RUN mkdir /app
--> Using cache 2b4db1bf5a55ef647872b0124002c09e52b374e9b21770cc9bcdbba0478b7600
--> 2b4db1bf5a55
STEP 3/8: COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
--> Using cache 988d928eaf37c4a36fc3784e5541e312ecc0dd0821a1e3d28f30f25cdd9f2c58
--> 988d928eaf37
STEP 4/8: RUN pip install --upgrade pip
--> Using cache 17bdfbe7dca62ca6b701b0da865ef9c6b80394fb0047478452dc975a77239f68
--> 17bdfbe7dca6
STEP 5/8: RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
--> Using cache 023535794e16df9e70973c878e6917a98956089e72cbd790b6d6b3486614b7ee
--> 023535794e16
STEP 6/8: COPY app /
--> Using cache de1369f0b343665f41a9c3c700468eb0beead97ab42d8c50a7c699443185276d
--> de1369f0b343
STEP 7/8: EXPOSE 80
--> Using cache e3e82da4b760f8af6e00cfd483a985c8d66189e566ab52bb84109940b65bf260
--> e3e82da4b760
STEP 8/8: CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
--> Using cache d4ef739224b0395fd3e4cfdc7ed3c9d1cfa7a17f6b915743eed4205ef38c0663
COMMIT default-service-fastpai:latest
--> d4ef739224b0
Successfully tagged localhost/default-service-fastpai:latest
Successfully tagged europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ml-deployment-417517/mldefault/default-service-fastpai:latest
d4ef739224b0395fd3e4cfdc7ed3c9d1cfa7a17f6b915743eed4205ef38c0663
(.venv) spool@fedora:~/Documents/Projects/Predicting_default$ podman tag default-service-fastpai europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ml-deployment-417517/mldefault/default-service-fastpai
(.venv) spool@fedora:~/Documents/Projects/Predicting_default$ podman push europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ml-deployment-417517/mldefault/default-service-fastpai
```

Does someone have any tips on this?

Comment: Your question does not show any errors

Comment: It is redundant to `podman build --tag=foo ...` and then `podman tag ${NAME} ${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${REGISTRY}/${NAME}`. You can more simply `podman build --tag=${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${REGISTRY}/${NAME} ...`